# AccuRev- 'files in Deep overlap' section

Tags: accurev

What I did:

- AccuRev update
- SourceCode does not compile any more and it should because it compiles on other machines
- I do not understand it so I delete my workspace from my HDD and I populate it back from AccuRev
- I get lots and lots of files in 'Underlap' and in 'Deep Overlap' state

Questions here:

- why did I get files in this status? (and how can I solve this problem, I reverted changes to files from 'Underlap' and now I am merging files from 'Deep Overlap' but there are lots of them!
- how can I just get files from repo?

Thank you!

Comment: If your workspace was up-to-date w/r/t to the backing stream, delete the workspace and create a new one from the backing stream.  (That might be a good idea anyway -- create a new wkspace from the backing stream -- so you could compare it to your troubled workspace.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The deep overlap filter will give you a list of overlap files in your workspace and/or files in a stream above your workspace.

For stream overlap, once you resolve the deep overlaps, you will need to promote those changes into the stream where the overlap appears to clear this status.

If you want a clean workspace wrt your basis stream, I would recommend you purge (revert to backed) any elements in your default group and pending filter.  Once complete, update the workspace.  Now your workspace should be identical with the basis stream.